# Is it possible to attribute a sortOrder value to a column based on the alphabetical order of the values of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Let's say we have a table with the columns:

```
name, sortOrder, productId
```

and you want to sort by name for a productId in particular.

Let's say that you have the following table:

```
name, sortOrder, productId
aaa1, 9, px10
aaa2, 2, px10
aaa4, 1, px10
bbb1, 3, px10
ccc1, 4, px10
ccc2, 8, px10
aaa5, 7, px11
aaa6, 5, px13
```

You want to run a stored procedure for px10 that attributes a value according to the alphabetical order of the rows based on the column name.

Running it would give:

```
name, sortOrder, productId
aaa1, 1, px10
aaa2, 2, px10
aaa4, 3, px10
bbb1, 4, px10
ccc1, 5, px10
ccc2, 6, px10
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL Server? I tried to look for a way, but I couldn't find any resource that told me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by name) as sortorder
from t;
```

If you want to update the table with this value:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by name) as new_sortorder
      from t
     )
update toupdate
     set sortorder = new_sortorder
     where sortorder <> new_sortorder;
```